# facebook login integration with codeigniter not returning user profile data

Tags: php, codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk

This is my code which I based on a video tutorial. How can  I get  user profile data after login? I am not getting any.

**//controller**

```
public function signin()
{
    $this->load->library('facebook');
    //   parse_str( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_REQUEST );
    $user = $this->facebook->getUser();

    if($user)
    {
        try{
            $data['user_profile']=$this->facebook->api('/me');
        }
        catch(FacebookApiException $e)
        {
            $user = null;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->facebook->destroySession();
    }        

    if($user)
    {
        $data['logout_url']= site_url('front_con/logout');  
    }
    else
    {
        $data['login_url']= $this->facebook->getLoginUrl( array('redirect_uri'=>site_url('front_con/signin'),
        'scope'=>array("email")));
    }
    // echo "kkksdf";
    $this->load->view('check',$data);
}


public function logout()
{  
    $this->load->library('facebook');
    $this->facebook->destroySession();
    redirect('front_con/signin');
}
```

**//here is my view**

```
<?php if(@$user_profile): ?>
<?=$user_profile['name']?>
<a href="<?= $logout_url; ?>">Click here to logout</a>
<?php var_dump($user_profile);?>
<?php else:?>
<a href="<?= $login_url; ?>">Click here to login</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: The ability to indent code with whitespace is included in most (if not all) languages for a reason. Please, for the sake of everyone trying to read your code, indent.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$_REQUEST += $_GET;`before the `getUser()`

```
$_REQUEST += $_GET; 
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

**Note** :

1. Facebook PHP SDK utilizes the `$_REQUEST` variable while CodeIgniter
   purges the `$_REQUEST` variable for security reasons.
2. To get around this, you may copy the content of `$_GET` to
   `$_REQUEST` before calling `getUser()`.